# .EntireRow.Delete Not Working in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use macros to delete filtered rows from a table in Excel. I Keep on running into issues with it deleting the data (Error #1004). Here is my code:

```
Dim RangeToDelete As Range
Set RangeToDelete = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("TableName").Offset(0, 1) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If Not RangeToDelete Is Nothing Then
    RangeToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Set RangeToDelete = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you have a range named `TableName`?

Comment: The `Set` line will error if you have no visible cells.

Comment: My range is named TableName. Is that an issue?

Comment: If `TableName` is referring to a table. That would be a `ListObject` rather than a `Range`.